# Deploying a RoR website on a linux machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, security

I am new to linux and RoR and was looking for some advice and best practices in respect to:

1. Path to my ruby source
2. Path to public folder
3. Permissions on each

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Capistrano, which is popular in the RoR community, uses `/u/apps/your_app/current` where current is a symlink to a timestamp directory with the latest version of the source code.  That's as reasonable a place as any, although I prefer `/var/www/your_app`. See this diagram. [image: https://raw.github.com/mpasternacki/capistrano-documentation-support-files/master/default-execution-path/Capistrano%20Execution%20Path.jpg]
2. leave it where RoR has it by default, under your rails application root
3. By default I use 570 (r-xrwx---) for directories and 460 (r--rw-----) for files with the owner set to www-data, which is the user my web server (nginx) and app server (RoR) execute as.  I set the group to a group called webadmin and add my login to that group so I can deploy and make changes.  If your app needs to write to any files or directories, add write permission to specific files/directories on an as-needed basis.